# How to solve vector equation?

Tags: equation-solving, vector

Given the vector relation $(\mathbf{a}+3 \mathbf{b}) \perp(7 \mathbf{a}-5 \mathbf{b})$, $(\mathbf{a}-4 \mathbf{b}) \perp(7 \mathbf{a}-2 \mathbf{b})$, find the angle between $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$.

$$\begin{array}{c}
\text{Solving process: } \qquad \because(\mathbf{a}+3 \mathbf{b}) \cdot(7 \mathbf{a}-5\mathbf{b}) = 0,(\mathbf{a}-4 \mathbf{b}) \cdot(7 \mathbf{a}-2 \mathbf{b}) = 0 \\
\therefore \quad 7 \mathbf{a}^{2}+16 \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}-15 \mathbf{b}^{2} = 0,7 \mathbf{a}^{2}-30 \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}+8 \mathbf{b}^{2} = 0\\
\quad \mathbf{a}^{2} = \mathbf{b}^{2} = 2 \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} \\
\Rightarrow \cos \langle \mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}\rangle = \frac{\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}}{\mathbf{a}|\cdot \mathbf{b}|} = \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}$$

```
a = {x1, y1, z1};
b = {x2, y2, z2};
Solve[{7 a . a + 16 a . b - 15 b . b == 0, 
   7 a . a - 30 a . b + 8 b . b == 0, 
   cosa == a . b/(Norm[a] Norm[b])}, 
  cosa, {x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2}] // FullSimplify
```

How to use Mathematica to directly solve the above vector equation and find the angle between vector $\mathbf{a}$  and vector $\mathbf{b}$? I wonder if there is any other easier way.

Comment: What's wrong with your solution? It's straightforward and includes elimination!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `Eliminate[]`:

```
With[{a = {a1, a2, a3}, b = {b1, b2, b3}}, 
     Eliminate[{(a + 3 b) . (7 a - 5 b) == 0, (a - 4 b) . (7 a - 2 b) == 0,
                cang == a . b/(Sqrt[a . a] Sqrt[b . b])}, Join[a, b]]]
   4 cang^2 == 1

Solve[%, cang]
   {{cang -> -1/2}, {cang -> 1/2}}
```

Only one of the two possible solutions is valid, however:

```
{(a + 3 b) . (7 a - 5 b) == 0, (a - 4 b) . (7 a - 2 b) == 0} /.
{a -> {1, 0, 0}, b -> Append[AngleVector[2 π/3], 0]}
   {False, False}

{(a + 3 b) . (7 a - 5 b) == 0, (a - 4 b) . (7 a - 2 b) == 0} /.
{a -> {1, 0, 0}, b -> Append[AngleVector[π/3], 0]}
   {True, True}
```